# Looking for an equivalent function without use if statement

Tags: c, function, if-statement

I’ve this function

```
int f(int x) {
  if (x == 0)
    return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Is possible to write an equivalent function without use the `if` statement?

Comment: `return x != 0`

Comment: There are a bunch of options. You can use the ternary operator. You can do what @WilliamPursell said. You can return `float(x) == -float(x)`. What’s your actual goal?

Comment: Sounds like homework help without any initial effort invested.

Comment: You can also replace `if` with `while` if you wish to make a point of what a pointless homework question this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function converts `x` to a boolean.

Instead of the `if` statement, you could use the ternary operator:

```
int f(int x) { return x ? 1 : 0; }
```

There are simpler ways to do this:

```
int f(int x) { return x != 0; }

int f(int x) { return !!x; }
```

You could even use the C99 `bool` type, but it is somewhat error prone:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
int f(int x) { return (bool)x; }
```

Here are some funny alternatives:

```
int f(int x) { return x>0|0>x; }
int f(int x) { return x<0|0<x; }
```

Comment: I am just curious: what is error-prone with `return (bool)x;` ?

Comment: @MartinR: the cast to `(bool)` only works with the standard `bool`, or more precisely `_Bool` type introduced in C99.  If `bool` is defined as `typedef unsigned char bool;` or `typedef int bool;`, as some pre-C99 environments do, it would fail silently. Thus this construction is unintuitive and should probably just be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
return x ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write: `return x != 0` ......

Comment: I'm curious if this is implementation dependent or not. This operation will return an `bool`. The return value of the function will eventually promote the type to `int`. But still C just defines `true` as different to `0`

Comment: @MarcoRamírez  "This operation will return an bool", no.  `x != 0` is an `int`, in C.  There is no `bool` or `_Bool` involved with `return x != 0`.